# Unable to run shopify api in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, shopify

I am working with Shopify and Nodejs,Right now i am trying to access "shopify" module with "express js" but right
now i am getting following errors

```
ShopifyError: Cannot initialize Shopify API Library. Missing values for: apiKey, apiSecretKey, hostName
    at new ShopifyError (node_modules\@shopify\shopify-api\lib\error.js:13:28)
    at validateConfig (node_modules\@shopify\shopify-api\lib\config.js:39:15)
    at Object.shopifyApi (node_modules\@shopify\shopify-api\lib\index.js:30:55)
    at shopifyApp (@shopify\shopify-app-express\build\cjs\index.js:26:26)
    at file:///C:/Users/Win%20-%20X/Downloads/themeflow-main/themeflow-main/web/shopify.js:39:17
```

```
Here is my current code In config.js (node_modules\@shopify\shopify-api\lib\config.js),where i am get "hostname" ?
```

```
 var config = {
        apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb54d7',
        apiSecretKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx004',
        scopes: new scopes_1.AuthScopes([]),
        hostName: '',
        hostScheme: 'https',
        apiVersion: types_1.LATEST_API_VERSION,
        isEmbeddedApp: true,
        isPrivateApp: false,
        logger: {
            log: defaultLogFunction,
            level: types_1.LogSeverity.Info,
            httpRequests: false,
            timestamps: false,
        },
    };
```

Comment: what if you put something like localhost for hostName?

Comment: How are you passing `config` to the library?